# Is there a security tracker aggregated file for Ubuntu server like Debian has?

Tags: ubuntu, cve, debian, package-manager

Debian has a JSON file containing all CVE<->Fixed package versions map. 
Link: https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/data/json

Does Ubuntu have something similar?

Comment: [Related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1113429/349837) about `debsecan` and `unattended-upgrade`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Ubuntu Security Advisory](https://usn.ubuntu.com/). It provides a mailing list, RSS feed, and Atom feed.

There is no API for historical data, according to a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/169467/796212) on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. The feeds only contains the latest vulnerabilities without historic data. I'm looking for en exhaustive list. But thank you for the replay.

Comment: @drdrek See my update. This question was also asked on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Just for completeness sake I would like to say that there is a better way to programmatically go over historic security information. We ended up going over the Ubuntu security repository getting the information by iterating over their files: https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/ubuntu-cve-tracker/master/files/head:/active/. I will keep your answer as the accepted answer because this is a very niche solution that is probably not relevant for most people. Its very disappointing that a such large distribution like Ubuntu lags behind so much on security visibility.